# Receiving corrupted response when writing xlsx file to HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, excel, spring, servlets, xlsx

I have a Spring controller that should return xlsx file:

```java
@PostMapping("/export")
public void exportExcelFile(
        HttpServletResponse response) {
       myService.exportExcel(response);
}
```

(using Post as I also need some data in request body to generate the file - I guess it is not related to the question).

Here is how I create file (using Apache POI 4.1.0) and write it to response:

```java
public void exportExcel(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.xlsx");

    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("My Sheet");
    Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue("abc");

    OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    workbook.write(outputStream);
    outputStream.flush();
    workbook.close();
}
```

However as a response body I'm receiving smth weird:

```
    PK�l%T[Content_Types].xml�S�n�0����*6�PU�C���\{�X�%����]8�R�
q�cfgfW�d�q�ZCB|��|�*�*h㻆},^�{Va�^K
<4�6�N�XQ�ǆ�9�!P��$��҆�d�c�D�j);��ѝP�g��E�M'O�ʕ����H7L�h���R���G��^�'�{��zސʮB��3�˙��h.�h�W�жF�j娄CQՠ똈���}ιL�U:D�����%އ����,�B���[� �� ;˱� �{N��~��X�p�ykOL��kN�V��ܿBZ~����q�� �ar��{O�PKz��q;PK�l%T_rels/.rels���j�0�_���8�`�Q��2�m��4[ILb��ږ���.[K
�($}��v?�I�Q.���uӂ�h���x>=��@��p�H"�~�}�   �n����*"�H�׺؁�����8�Z�^'�#��7m{��O�3���G�u�ܓ�'��y|a�����D�    ��l_EYȾ����vql3�ML�eh���*���\3�Y0���oJ׏�  :��^��}PK��z��IPK�l%TdocProps/app.xmlM��
�0D�~EȽ��ADҔ���A? ��6�lB�J?ߜ���0���ͯ�)�@��׍H6���V>��$;�SC
;̢(�ra�g�l�&�e��L!y�%��49��`_���4G���F��J��Wg
�GS�b����
~�PK�|wؑ�PK�l%TdocProps/core.xmlm��J�0E��=I�B�A�Aq�ŷ��bs!�v�{�:VPߒ�u'�������5
a%i�`��<��9�BF��l��d���qi=�u��!K�t
�ct ��E"L
_��"����    �*:���S��Q�,��j$G���ҽ�q( 8�F�����������!+5MS1U�6b�t{s�,�f��D��G5�ED�%�.5�
    <V�W�-iKZ�9e9=�3ƫ3^��~��¯���E*��lww=s�s
jn?PKm����PK�l%Txl/sharedStrings.xml=�1�0НSDީB(M$N�i#5N���Ƨ����?i6o*3wphZ0�!�������Y5!o��f�nt��n�t0�.D %/M^�k��%y�,#�R�2i��ض'L>28+�Yu�,���#�S�PK?�1��PK�l%T
xl/styles.xml���n� ��>bop2TQ��P)U�RWb�6*�����ӤS�Nw�s���3ߍ֐���t��(l��������ҝx�!N=@$ɀ��}��3c���ʰr`:i��2��w,�
�d
�T��R#�voc �;c�iE��Û��E<|��4Iɣ����F#��n���B�z�F���y�j3y��yҥ�jt>���2��Lژ�!6��2F�OY��4@M�!���G��������1�t��y��p��" n����u�����a�ΦDi�9�&#��%I��9��}���cK��T��$?������`J������7���o��f��M|PK�1X@C�PK�l%Txl/workbook.xml���N�0��
        <E�;K
A�t�MH�!4�g��Fk��  �Oک����˟?���ˏ⌜
�J��Бu��}�r������D'Q�49�Z��
�MZQ�P6=�7�D>��Mb���S�Qz�\
5��A}�:�R��1䫄q4��M��    ڟf�,��X=�
��l�i���~�)
�ewƽ9hP'��s�e�`
            <jؐ�
#q���xg�A�Ю�j�,�r��~PK9��p�bPK�l%Txl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels��Mk�0@���}q���n/c����c+qh"K�迟���@;�$��{��~Γy�"#���i� �#
^�O7�`D=E?1�b�n��8y�?$�YLE�8H���Z     g/
g����^�6�p��U���r΀%�좃����/�I�`|�Rˤ��:f����~���mF�v�����:���ׯ�������p9HB�SyݵK~�����PK�;��3PK�l%Txl/worksheets/sheet1.xmleP]K�@|�W�n.U�"I� E����l���۰�m��>,�3���o?�PtJ��r� 4غЗ��c{y�7�E1#���J�!�z`����'r鐼e�ԛ8�v��\�����]����"�J��Ҧ*◃9��U�w <���xl�w�a̴��6���%�+�:��
�'p���r-5O���mUΊ�"隴H&%�(�P�9�E##���Q8�^,�.DU#3z   �ݮ��(�k�y�����Ҋ����q�զB�W?PK⺫��PK�l%Tz��q;[Content_Types].xmlPK�l%T��z��I|_rels/.relsPK�l%T�|wؑ��docProps/app.xmlPK�l%Tm����gdocProps/core.xmlPK�l%T?�1���xl/sharedStrings.xmlPK�l%T�1X@C�
uxl/styles.xmlPK�l%T9��p�b�xl/workbook.xmlPK�l%T�;��3
xl/_rels/workbook.xml.relsPK�l%T⺫��)    xl/worksheets/sheet1.xmlPK        ?{
```

The question is how to receive a non-corrupted response? As I checked, if I write the workbook into file (e.g.

```java
File file = new File("test.xlsx");
workbook.write(new FileOutputStream(file));
workbook.close();
```

), the file looks well. However if I copy the content of the file to response:

```java
IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(file), response.getOutputStream());
response.flushBuffer();
```

I receive the same corrupted response. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution:

1- Service:

```
 public static ByteArrayInputStream prepareData()  {
            try(Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook()){
                Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("data");

                Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
                CellStyle headerCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
                headerCellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.AQUA.getIndex());
                headerCellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
                // Creating header
                Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
                cell.setCellValue("First Name");
                cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);

                cell = row.createCell(1);
                cell.setCellValue("Last Name");
                cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);

                cell = row.createCell(2);
                cell.setCellValue("Mobile");
                cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);

                cell = row.createCell(3);
                cell.setCellValue("Email");
                cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);

                // Creating data rows for each customer
                for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                    Row dataRow = sheet.createRow(i + 1);
                    dataRow.createCell(0).setCellValue("FirstName " + i);
                    dataRow.createCell(1).setCellValue("LastName " + i);
                    dataRow.createCell(2).setCellValue("Mobile " + i);
                    dataRow.createCell(3).setCellValue("Email " + i);
                }

                // Making size of column auto resize to fit with data
                sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);
                sheet.autoSizeColumn(1);
                sheet.autoSizeColumn(2);
                sheet.autoSizeColumn(3);

                ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                workbook.write(outputStream);
                return new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
```

2- Controller:

```
    @PostMapping("/export")
    public void exportExcelFile(
            HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=data.xlsx");
        ByteArrayInputStream stream = ServiceXLS.prepareData();
        IOUtils.copy(stream, response.getOutputStream());
    }
```

Comment: Same, receiving corrupted data.

Comment: Output :First Name Last Name Mobile Email
FirstName 0 LastName 0 Mobile 0 Email 0
FirstName 1 LastName 1 Mobile 1 Email 1
FirstName 2 LastName 2 Mobile 2 Email 2
FirstName 3 LastName 3 Mobile 3 Email 3
FirstName 4 LastName 4 Mobile 4 Email 4
FirstName 5 LastName 5 Mobile 5 Email 5
FirstName 6 LastName 6 Mobile 6 Email 6
FirstName 7 LastName 7 Mobile 7 Email 7